# Can't run XCUI tests in xcode

Tags: xcode, xcuitest

My xCode IDE is not displaying the diamond shaped play button used to execute the xcui tests.  It actually existed a few weeks ago and disappeared from the IDE.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling xCode to no avail.  I can run the tests from the Product menu, but the problem is it runs all of the tests in the solution.  I need to be able to only run one test at a time.  I'm using xCode 13.2.1

My tests are prefixed with "test" in the function name but the diamond icon still does not appear.
I also noticed the 'record' button is disabled at the bottom.

Please help, I've been stuck for a week.

Comment: What happens when you set up a new UI testing target? Xcode should provide you with some example test cases.

Comment: @MikeCollins. i resolved the issue by deleting the repo and cloning again.

Comment: Great! Cleaning the build folder (in Xcode) may have had the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have faced this issue before, some steps to fix :

1. Try cleaning the build folder and build again
2. Try deleting the whole project once and clone again

If still facing , check for any updates pending in Xcode or try deleting and reinstalling xcode again.

Hope this helps :)